# How to create datetime index from month and year columns, but without day?

Tags: python, datetime

My dataframe has 'Year' and 'Month' columns. I wish to create a datetime index for this monthly dataframe, letting the date be implicitly the last day of the month.

It is a simple question but I have been looking for an hour without success.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
df['date0'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Month'].astype(str)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date0'])
df.resample('M').last()
```

Comment: Thanks!  The other answer did not work for me, though I was doing something slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df.index = [datetime.datetime(df[1].Year,df[1].Month,1)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0) for df in df.iterrows()]
```